# SQL is always check the first result only

Tags: php, sql

I have SQL table "ip_logs"

[image]

What i trying to do:
if the member Ip $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] have already in the ip_logs table..this message will appear "Sorry !! "

The problem is the system is always check the first IP only in the ip_logs table

My code is :

```
<?
  $link=mysql_connect("localhost","DBUSER","DBPASS","DBNAME") ;
  mysql_select_db("DBNAME",$link) ;

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_logs");
    $rexu=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

if( $rexu[routing_ip]=="".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."" ) { 
echo ' Sorry !! ';
}
?>
```

Please help me..what is wrong ?!

Comment: Store IP addresses as actual numbers, not as strings in dotted-quad notation

Answer (score 3):

You want to search for a single IP, not a batch.

Do something like:

```
'SELECT routing_ip FROM ip_logs WHERE routing_ip = "'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'"'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're:

- Querying *all* records
- Retrieving (just) the first result
- Checking it against your condition

Instead, you want to:

- Query for *one* record that matches your condition

SQL already has condition capabilities (`WHERE`), so use them.

Answer (score 1):

you are using [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) which fech just the first row , you need to use [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)  :

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_logs");
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($results as $result){
       if( $result[routing_ip]=="".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."" ) { 
               echo ' Sorry !! ';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_logs");

for($x = 1 ; $x <= mysql_num_rows($sql) ; $x++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    if( $row[routing_ip]=="".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."" ) { 
        echo ' Sorry !! ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_logs");

if ($sql != NULL && mysql_num_rows($sql)>0)
{

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
{
 if ($row->routing_ip == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) { echo ' Sorry !! ';}
}

}
```